# Problems with staggered Text and button

Tags: css, html, button

I have problems with the placement of the button and the paragraph/text. They are placed in a staggered way. I want them to be placed on a straight horizontal line. You can see the problem on the image below. 
Further more, I want the button to be placed right above the end of the "hr" line, the same way as the paragraph is placed above the left side of the line. Any idea for a solution?

[image]

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AdiT/62QY8/92/)

HTML:

```
<!--Wrapper div-->
    <div id="wrapper">

        <!--Inbox list and button to add a card-->
        <div id="inboxList" class="cellContainer">
            <br style="line-height: 23px" />
            <p class="paragraph">In-Box</p>
            <!--Button to add a Card-->
            <div id="btnAddCard" style="float: right;"><span          
            style="color: #10e20e; font-size:140%" >+</span> Add Card...</div>
            <hr class="fancy-line" />
            <br />

            <!--Card div-->
            <div id="userAddedCard"> <br/>
                <div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#btnAddCard {
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 0.7% 2% 1% 2%; /* Button padding */
    font-size: 95%;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline;
    text-decoration: none; /* Remove default underline style from hyperlink */
    color: #888888;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border-radius: 7px; /* Full rounder corners */
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}


#btnAddCard {
    background: rgb(255,255,255); /* Old browsers */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(229,229,229,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e5e5e5',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

.paragraph {
    padding-left:7%;
    display:inline;
    font-family:cursive;
    font:bolder;
    font-size:larger;

}

hr.fancy-line {
    height: 1.8px;
    background-color: blueviolet;
    width:85%;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `p.paragraph` to `<div.paragraph>` and Adding `margin-left:7%` and removing the `font-size` of `140%` from `#btnAddCard`  seems to have fixed the problem

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/62QY8/93/)

**Update:**

I'd simply put the contents in a div, give it proper margin and highlight it's bottom border instead of the `<hr>` so that the children will align perfectly, something like this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/62QY8/95/)

*Side note: please avoid using inline-styles and tags such as `<br>` `<center>` etc, it makes maintenance easier [Why Use CSS @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_Started/Why_use_CSS)*